# JQuery Datepicker "defaultDay: '-18Y'" save in a var

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Excuse me, my English is very bad, so I write with Google translate.

In JQuery, there is a very simple way to return by datepicker and defaultDate 18 years, but can you also store it in a variable?

```
$('#geburtsdatum').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  prevText: 'zurück',
  nextText: 'vor',
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
  showOtherMonths: true,
  monthNames: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
  dayNamesMin: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
  defaultDate: '-18Y',
  onSelect: function(date) {
    var birthday = date;
  }
});
```

I can write the selected date into a variable, but not the defaultDate with -18Y.

Has anyone there perhaps a tip?

Comment: It's just a string. What have you tried?

Comment: It is that you can choose his birthday and I would like to check right over the date of birth whether the person is over 18 years old or not (if the person is not over 18 years old, something XY should happen ...)

Comment: Is done! Combined with old JavaScript methods ... but it rocks ;)
How can I close this helpless question?